# Homeomorphism between $[0,1]$ and the extended real line $\mathbb{R} \cup \{\pm \infty\}$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I know that $[-1,1]$ and the extended real line $\overline{\mathbb{R}}$ are homeomorphic. Is it also true that $[0,1]$ and $\overline{\mathbb{R}}$ are homeomorphic? If so how can we show that?

Comment: What are your thoughts on the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find a homeomorphism between $[0,1]$ and $[-1,1]$. Since compositions of bijective resp. continuous functions are bijective resp. continuous, this will imply that $[0,1]$ and $\overline{\mathbb{R}}$ are homeomorphic.

Comment: that was easy (; Thanks!

Comment: @wayne I'll leave it up to you to find the homeomorphism (hint: the most obvious bijection will do). Feel free to accept the answer if you think it helped you.

Comment: When I consider the map $f: [0,1] \rightarrow [-1,1]$ with $f(x) = 2 \cdot x - 1$ then f is obviously continuous and bijective

Comment: @wayne Exactly! And its inverse is too.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f:[0,1]\rightarrow[-\infty,\infty]$ be a function defined by
$$
f(x)=\begin{cases}
\tan(\pi(x-\frac{1}{2})), & \mbox{ if }x\in(0,1)\\
\infty, & \mbox{ if }x=1\\
-\infty, & \mbox{ if }x=0
\end{cases}.
$$
It can be verified that $f$ is a homeomorphism.

Answer (score 0):

Define the function  $f(x) = \tan ( \pi /2) x$ for $0<x<1$ and $f(-1)= -\infty $ , $f(1)= \infty$

The function f is a homeomorphism  from $[-1,1]$ to $ \overline{\mathbb{R}}$

We know that $[0,1]$ is homeomophic to $ [-1,1]$